# Pharo punctuation marks

Tags: regex, pharo, punctuation

Is there any way to capture all the places in a String, where there are punctuation marks like '.,:;!?'

Basically, am looking for a regex that captures all the above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a character class. A character class is a group of characters that you're saying can be matched at that position in the string. To make a character class you enclose your list of matchable characters in square brackets, like this:

```
[.,:;!?]
```

This will match only those punctuation characters.

Interestingly, you can also make a character class that will match anything except the list of characters you've specified. To do this, you start your character class with a `^`.

```
[^.,:;!?]
```

Now this one will match anything except punctuation.